# Undefined offset: 0 after a loop using arrayholder in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5

please help me figure this out. I just want to get the total quantity of the same inventory_record_id, as the image is shown below. And I wanted to store that total to an array name `$salesQtyArrayHldr`. However, it always return the undefined offset 0 error. Please help. Here is my code.

[image]

```
<?php 
    $salesQtyArrayHldr = array();
?>

    @foreach($inventory as $val)

     <?php
          for($i = 0; $i < count($val->sales); $i++){
            if($val->id == $val->sales[$i]->inventory_record_id ){
                $salesQtyArrayHldr[$i] += $val->sales[$i]->quantity; 
            } 
           }  
           var_dump($salesQtyArrayHldr);
    ?>
```

Error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($val->sales); $i++){
                if($val->id == $val->sales[$i]->inventory_record_id ){
                    if(isset($salesQtyArrayHldr[$val->id])){
                      $salesQtyArrayHldr[$val->id] += $val->sales[$i]->quantity; 
                    }else{
                    $salesQtyArrayHldr[$val->id] = 0; 
                    $salesQtyArrayHldr[$val->id] += $val->sales[$i]->quantity; 
                  }
                }
           }
```

Answer (score 2):

So check if isset:

```
if (isset($val->sales[$i])) {
    // action...
}
```

Comment: Oh.. i see now. Error is here: $salesQtyArrayHldr[$i] += $val->sales[$i]->quantity;. Probable $salesQtyArrayHldr[$i] is not isset.

Comment: So, if(isset($salesQtyArrayHldr[$i])), this is what I should do?

Comment: It returns an empty array value.

Comment: No. You should be sure that element exists: if (!isset($salesQtyArrayHldr[$i])) { $salesQtyArrayHldr[$i] = 0; }

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no such key in array **$val->sales**
Use helper **dd()** to check the structure of this variable.